# Where is babel plugin syntax defined?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, transpiler, acorn

I'm building a babel plugin and can find numerous examples of already written plugins in the Babel repo.

What I can't find is a definitive API documentation for writing such a plugin- especially for operations I can perform on the resulting AST.

I have checked

- [babel itself](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core#transform) (which is also what's linked from the ASTExplorer README
- [Acorn documentation](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/tree/master/acorn)
- Googled "Babel transform API"
- [The Babel Handbook](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/README.md)
- [Mozilla Parser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API) and the [ESTree API](https://github.com/estree/estree) linked therein

Just to list a few of the places. None of which have even defined the ubiquitous `.get` method I see called so often in existing plugins, to say nothing of other functions I can call on a path, node, scope, or binding.

Does a definitive source of documentation exist for Babel 7 transforms? If so, where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a "babel" expert, but after a few hours, that is what I've found out. There is no documentation about API rather than the actual source code.

As an example, I've decided to use this plugin, called [babel-plugin-transform-spread](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/eea156b2cb8deecfcf82d52aa1b71ba4995c7d68/packages/babel-plugin-transform-spread/src/index.js). Open those links as we go further.

The first stop is [AST Spec](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-parser/ast/spec.md). In the source code of the plugin above I see some [`CallExpression`](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-parser/ast/spec.md#callexpression), which can easily be found in the spec. According to spec, this **Type** has a couple of properties *(e.g. callee and arguments)*. And I can see a clear usage of them in the source code too. Nothing special at this point.

But you might want to ask: okay, but what about methods?

Let's have a look at `ArrayExpression` for example. There are no methods in the spec. But in the source code, there are a lot of them, like `.replaceWith()`. Where the heck did this come from? I found this [API doc](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-babel-core/build/apidoc.html). Quite old, yes, but still helpful IMO. Try to find `replaceWith` on this page and you will see some hints like `babel-core.traverse.NodePath.prototype.replaceWith`.

Okay, the next step is to open [babel's GitHub page](https://github.com/babel/babel) and to find something about **replaceWith** in `babel/packages/babel-traverse`. That leads us to [this line](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/eea156b2cb8deecfcf82d52aa1b71ba4995c7d68/packages/babel-traverse/src/path/replacement.js#L102). And right here you can see other related methods.

As an exercise, you can open **babel handbook** and try to find something else. `getPrevSibling` for example. And again, open GitHub, open search, see the results, and [here we go](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/eea156b2cb8deecfcf82d52aa1b71ba4995c7d68/packages/babel-traverse/src/path/family.js#L112). Or [`findParent`](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/eea156b2cb8deecfcf82d52aa1b71ba4995c7d68/packages/babel-traverse/src/path/ancestry.js#L13), or [`insertAfter`](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/eea156b2cb8deecfcf82d52aa1b71ba4995c7d68/packages/babel-traverse/src/path/modification.js#L94), etc.

This method is not the easiest one, but without proper documentation, this is what we have to deal with. Unfortunately.

Comment: Can you expand on "There is no documentation about API..."? Is that an authoritative claim from the Babel team or a statement of your discoveries so far?

Comment: Good point. I've found [this issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7899) related to your question. The core maintainer answering about "supposed methods" said, "If you are asking about API methods, then yes we don't have them". Furthermore, I couldn't find any proper docs as well as you, not because they're hiding it from us, but because it doesn't exist. Otherwise, I don't see any good reason to have API documentation and hide it from the public.